# BizTalk message routing issue

Tags: routes, biztalk

We have a very simple integration that has one receive location (Rcv_01, WCF-BasicHttp) and two send ports (Snd_01, Snd_02, both of type WCF-BasicHttp). There is no orchestration used here. When an exception occurs, the message gets suspended and we get a log to the eventviewer. All fine and working as expected.

The issue now is that if an exception occurs we need to notify the sending party that the message failed due to some reason (missing data, not well-formed address etc).
So we created a third send port (Sp_ErrorHandler, FILE) with a filter to route any messages that fail to another folder. The end goal is to notify the sender with an email about the error and the failed message.

So, we have turned on Failed Message Routing and  with an appropiate filter we now get all the messages that are supposed to fail routed to a folder. But, we are now missing any information about the actual error and why the message failed. I cant find the error or information about it, whether I look in BizTalk admin console or the event viewer.

Can someone please explain to me if this is intended? We still need to know why a message has been rerouted. How can we solve this issue and if this is not how to do, then how do we do it? Are we forced to create an orchestration to get the behaviour we want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you probably need an Orchestration.

Even the Microsoft sample [Using the Exception Management Framework](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/biztalk/esb-toolkit/using-the-exception-management-framework) used an Orchestration.